# Design and implement the class Day that implements the day of the week in a program

Tags: java

I have a program to write with the following requirements:

Design and implement the class Day that implements the day of the week in a program.  The class Day should store the day, such as Sun for Sunday.  The program should be able to perform the following operations on an object of type Day:

A. Set the day.

B. Print the day.

C. Return the day.

D. Return the next day.

E. Return the previous day.

F. Calculate and return the day by adding certain days to the current day.  For example, if the current day is Monday and we add four days, the day to be returned is Friday.  Similarly, if today is Tuesday and we add 13 days, the day to be returned is Monday.

G. Add the appropriate constructors.

H. Write the definitions of the methods to implement the operations for the class Day, as defined in A through G.

I. Write a program to test various operations on the class Day.

Now, I've looked at the various thread on this and other sites, read my materials, and have gotten my program just about there.  I'm just having one nagging issue: Sunday.  The code below does everything I expect for every day of the week, except Sunday.

When I set ourDay to SUN, I do get the nextDay, 10 days out etc, but I keep getting a blank return for previousDay.  I've tried various ways to go about this, but I keep coming back to the way it's written below as being the way it should work, but it's not.  I know that I can't handle SUN the same as other days, since I can't subtract 1 from that and expect a value the program can return properly, which is why I've told it to set ourDay as SAT if the value is SUN.

Any and all assistance would be much appreciated, as I believe I'm missing something simple here, and am just beating my head against the wall at this point.

**EDIT**  Thanks everyone for your input.  Using your feedback I've changed the code, updated source is provided below.  For some reason, I'm still getting a blank output for previousDay, although all other functions are working.  I cleaned up a lot, as some of you pointed out I was doing some things that did not need to be done and were redundant.

At this point I'm almost ready to scrap the approach I've taken and move to using an enum or array.  Any thoughts to that, or should I stick with what I have so far?

FYI my output looks like this when I run:
The current day: Sunday
The previous day: 
The next day: Monday
10 days later: Thursday

```
    public class Day

{
        final static int SUN = 0;
        final static int MON = 1;
        final static int TUE = 2;
        final static int WED = 3;
        final static int THU = 4;
        final static int FRI = 5;
        final static int SAT = 6;                 

        public static int ourDay;         

        public void setDay()
        {this.ourDay = ourDay;} 

        public void DayType()
        {this.ourDay = ourDay;}

        public int nextDay()
        {
            if (ourDay == SAT)
            {return SUN;}

            else
            {ourDay = (ourDay + 1) % 7;}            
            return ourDay;           
        }                  

        public int previousDay() 
        {
            if (ourDay == SUN)
            {return SAT;}

            else
            {ourDay = (ourDay - 1) % 7;}        
            return ourDay;           
        }       

        public int futureDay(int ourDays) 
        {return (ourDay + ourDays) % 7;}

        public String toString()        
        {
            switch (this.ourDay) 
               {
                  case SUN:
                        return "Sunday";
                  case MON:
                        return "Monday";
                  case TUE:
                        return "Tuesday";
                  case WED:
                        return "Wednesday";
                  case THU:
                        return "Thursday";
                  case FRI:
                        return "Friday";
                  case SAT:
                        return "Saturday";
                }
                  return "";
        }    

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
                DayType outDay = new DayType(SUN);                
                System.out.print("The current day: " + outDay);                
                System.out.println();
                outDay.setDay(outDay.previousDay());
                System.out.print("The previous day: " + outDay);                               
                System.out.println();
                outDay.setDay(outDay.nextDay());                
                outDay.setDay(outDay.nextDay());
                System.out.print("The next day: " + outDay);              
                System.out.println();                               
                outDay.setDay(outDay.futureDays(10));
                System.out.print("10 days later: " + outDay);               
                System.out.println();               
        }       
}
```

Comment: You should *return* SAT as the previous day. Not *change the current day* to SAT, and the  change it again.

Comment: where is the code for DayType ??

Comment: Why do you set ourDay to SAT explicitly and then calculate explicitly  ourDay with %7 in both previous and nextDay() methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your explanation I guess your methot shoul look like this:

```
public int previousDay() 
        {
            if (ourDay == SUN) {
              return SAT;
            } else {                           
              return (ourDay - 1) % 7;
            }          
        }
```

You first treated SUN like a special case, but then you overwrite 'ourDay' with regular calculations.

As mentioned by @JB Nizet, you method should also return calculated day, without changing value of 'ourDay'. Code edited.

Here's the output of modified method 'previousDay()':

```
The current day: Sunday
The previous day: Saturday
```

Missing DayType forced changes in main() class, so if you can't get the expected output yourself feel free to ask, or include all the relevant code to your example.

Comment: This still sets the current day to the previous day, instead of simply returning the previous day as asked.

Comment: Why don't you amend your answer instead?

Comment: @JBNizet You're right again. I'm just tired and cranky :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I've updated my code and posted it above with some additional comments.  Unfortunately I'm still getting nothing for previousDay, which is baffling me.  I'd almost rather get a wrong answer than nothing at all.

Comment: @JHCummins try debugging your code. only logical place for empty string is in your toString() method. Instead of returning "" try printing value of ourDay, or throwing some exception. You still didn't include DayType, so I assume your bug is there.

Comment: @zubergu  Thank you.  I went through steeping debug on my code, and when using SUN as my day, it sets the value for previousDay to -1, so in that regard it makes sense why I'm getting nothing, since there is no day declared with that value.  Also, please excuse my ignorance, but when you say I didn't include DayType, what do you mean?  I'm guessing I need to have a section earlier to handle it in some way?

Comment: @JHCummins In you code you're instantiating object with `new DayType()` but I can't see code for this class, so I'm wondering what that really is. If you're getting -1 it means that you didn't apply my fix or applied it in wrong place. If you want me, or anyone else for that matter, to look into your problem, please make sure that code you posted compiles and runs as is. Without this any attempt to help will be just another guess.

Comment: @zubergu Oh my, I can't believe I missed that.  I have been staring at the screen so long, and going through so many iterations, that I completely forgot I changed Day to DayType, and at some point must have deleted the code up above to handle it!  I changed it back to Day, and put back the code necessary and everything works as advertised now.  Thank you!

Comment: @JHCummins If my answer helped you solve the problem, consider upvoting and accepting it as the correct one.

Comment: @zubergu Thanks again, I have marked yours as the correct answer and posted my working code separately in case it helps anyone else. Unfortunately since I'm so new lack the reputation to up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Working code is below.  Thanks to everyone for your comments, as they really did make a difference and I was able to trim some lines, correct a method or two, and realize I was missing some important stuff as well.

public class Day

```
{
        final static int SUN = 0;
        final static int MON = 1;
        final static int TUE = 2;
        final static int WED = 3;
        final static int THU = 4;
        final static int FRI = 5;
        final static int SAT = 6;                 

        public int ourDay;         

        public Day(int ourDay)
        {this.ourDay = ourDay;}

        public void setDay(int ourDay)
        {this.ourDay = ourDay;}         

        public int getDay()
        {return ourDay;}

        public int followingDay()
        {
            if (ourDay == SAT)
            {return SUN;}

            else {ourDay = (ourDay + 1) % 7;}            
            return ourDay;           
        }                  

        public int previousDay() 
        {
            if (ourDay == 0)
            {return SAT;}

            else {ourDay = (ourDay - 1) % 7;}        
            return ourDay;           
        }       

        public int futureDay(int ourDays) 
        {return ((ourDay + ourDays) -1 ) % 7;}

        public String toString()        
        {
            switch (this.ourDay) 
               {
                  case SUN:
                        return "Sunday";
                  case MON:
                        return "Monday";
                  case TUE:
                        return "Tuesday";
                  case WED:
                        return "Wednesday";
                  case THU:
                        return "Thursday";
                  case FRI:
                        return "Friday";
                  case SAT:
                        return "Saturday";
                }
                  return "";
        }    

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
                Day outDay = new Day(SUN);                
                System.out.print("The current day: " + outDay);                
                System.out.println();
                outDay.setDay(outDay.previousDay());
                System.out.print("The previous day: " + outDay);                               
                System.out.println();
                outDay.setDay(outDay.followingDay());                
                outDay.setDay(outDay.followingDay());
                System.out.print("The next day: " + outDay);              
                System.out.println();                               
                outDay.setDay(outDay.futureDay(10));
                System.out.print("10 days later: " + outDay);               
                System.out.println();               
        }       
}
```